# How can I preview a contribution page

Tags: contribution-page

I am creating a number of different contribution pages for membership levels and I find it confusing without being able to preview a contribution page to see if I have it configured correctly.
I am using CiviCRM in Joomla 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Hi Paul and Welcome to CiviCRM StackExchange.

You can preview a contribution page like this:

1. In the Navigation click on "Contribution" --> "Manage Contribution Pages"
2. You will find a list of contribution pages and on the right side "Links" which has "Live contribution page" (creating actual payments) and "Test Drive" (creating test contributions BUT real contacts)

Click on the link you want to use. To see the page as a visitor would, open the link in a private window of the browser.

Comment: Thank you, Fabian! I don't know how I could have missed that but, like so many things, its easy when someone shows you the way. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome I have many such moments myself ^^ Please mark the questions answered if it works for you.